# Where does K8s store the logs that it prints when running kubectl logs -f

Tags: kubernetes

1. I am pretty sure it writes it on disk somewhere. Otherwise if the container runs for several hours and logs a lot, then it would exceed what the stderr can hold I think. No?
2. Is it possible to compress and download the logs of kubectl logs?i.e. comparess on the container without downloading them?

Comment: Have you looked at [Logging Architecture](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/logging/) in the Kubernetes documentation?  Does your application code need to access another container's logs, or are you merely concerned about log management?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly take a look on [logging-kubernetes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/logging/) official documentation.

In most cases, Docker container logs are put in the  `/var/log/containers`  directory on your host (host they are deployed on). Docker supports multiple logging drivers but Kubernetes API does not support driver configuration.

Once a container terminates or restarts,  *kubelet*  keeps its logs on the node. To prevent these files from consuming all of the host’s storage, a log rotation mechanism should be set on the node.

You can use `kubectl logs` to retrieve logs from a previous instantiation of a container with `--previous` flag, in case the container has crashed.

If you want to take a look at additional logs. For example, in Linux journald logs can be retrieved using the  `journalctl` command:

```
$ journalctl -u docker
```

You can implement cluster-level logging and expose  or push logs directly from every application but the implementation for such a logging mechanism is not in the scope of Kubernetes.

Also there are many tools offered for Kubernetes for logging management and aggregation - see: [logs-tools](https://logz.io/blog/open-source-monitoring-tools-for-kubernetes/).